# Prevent video downloading on mobile / javascript media query width

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, zurb-foundation

I have two layouts for a website- one for mobile one for desktop.

I am using Zurb Foundation which hides desktop layout on mobile and vice versa.

As the desktop layout contains videos I would like to prevent browser from downloading that part of the page if possible.

Can I use JavaScript query like this

```
    if (screen.width >= 600) {

<div>Video goes here</div>

    }
```

to do this? Would this work and would this prevent this part of the page downloading on screens smaller than 600px?

Answer (score 0):

Your browser shouldn't load your video if you use `preload` attribute with `none` value:

```
<video id="myVideo" preload="none"></video>
```

Later in your js you can load your video conditionally when you want:

```
if (screen.width >= 600) {
   var myVideo = document.getElementById('myVideo');
   myVideo.load();
   myVideo.play();
}
```

Comment: Do you think a valid solution would be to exclude video links from html and than have jQuery conditional script that inserts path to video only if the screen is wider than 600px?

Comment: It could be a valid approach, but you will have to test it to see if you get that you want.

Comment: Why would preload="none" be redundant? If the screen is smaller than 600px then preload is set to "none" and the video is not loaded, but if it is greater then js tells browser to load the video anyway. Correct or not?

Answer (score 0):

Load the video only if screen `width` is equal or higher than `600px` like this:

```
if($(window).width() >= 600) {
    loadVid();
}

function loadVid() {
   video = '<video src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" controls></video>';
   $(".video").append(video);
}
```

**[---> Working resizable Fiddle <---](https://jsfiddle.net/Syden/ozeuoLtp/1/)** (to test in other widths first resize, then run code)

Comment: Thanks! But let's say I am targeting iPhone 7 and set my break point to be 750px. What would happen if user rotates the phone to horizontal orientation? Would no video be served then?

Comment: I'd say it would depend on screen width by the time the user loads the page, if rotation is done after loading the site it should be there. Also, in that case you could just tweak the breakpoint value in the jQuery to cover landscape as well, or you could target by user agent but this would be more complex considering you would have to include most mobile browser agents.

Comment: I am trying the above with this code:


if($(window).width() > 750) {
    loadVid1();
}

function loadVid1() {
   video1 = '<video id="myVideo" data-autoplay><source src="<?php bloginfo("template_directory"); ?>/IMAGES/GameofThrones.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>';
   $("#three").prepend(video1);
}

But this is not working!? Any idea why?

Comment: You have a space on your closing php tag `; ?>`. Works fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/Syden/ozeuoLtp/3/

Comment: Still not working!? I thought it may be something to do with using quotes inside quotes but that doesn't solve it either!?

Comment: No idea then, the codes seems fine, quotes are being used correctly since they are opposite to the starting ones, it could be a path thing or the php...